# Why there is no retain loop between UINavigationController and UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, retain-cycle

Situation: there is UINavigationController with pushed UIViewController.

1.UIViewController has strong reference to UINavigationController

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UINavigationController *navigationController
```

2.UINavigationController stores view controllers in NSArray

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *viewControllers;
```

UINavigationController should have strong reference to this NSArray (or it will be deallocated).

3.NSArray has strong references to contained view controllers.

UPDATE:
Lets imagine somewhere in code we have following:

```
UIViewController *A = [ [UIViewController alloc] init ];
UINavigationController *B = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController:A ];
// Here we have strong reference in A to B, in B to B.viewControllers (count == 1) and in B.viewControllers to A.
// Local variable's strong references to A and B
A = nil; B = nil;
// Local variable's strong references has gone
// But we should still have retain loop here
// Magic !?? :)
```

My question is why we do not have retain loop here?

Comment: Your point 3 is true only when for the viewControllers that are in the stack. It is no longer true when a ViewController is removed (dismissed).

Comment: Please see my sample (below UPDATE) Where view controller is popped?

Comment: There _is_ a loop, but because it can be broken, it's not a problem. Not all reference loops are actually problems. Your code snippet doesn't change Vincent's answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell But what breaks it? I see how it can be broken if the child is popped off the stack, but here all that happens is that we stop referring to (retaining) the nav controller and its root view controller. If they are truly retaining each other, that's a retain loop and there is no way either one can ever receive `dealloc` (the retain count cannot reach zero).

Comment: The simplest explanation is a bug in the docs / public header. (And you could file a bug on that grounds.) But we will never know, since we cannot see Apple's code. Suffice it to say that there is _in fact_ no retain loop, since the nav controller and its root view controller do _in fact_ go out of existence together. That's all one needs to know.

Comment: @matt I know that there is no real retain loop (see topic title). I am just interesting why we do not have it? I like your idea that we can have some hidden functionality inside Apple's methods.

Comment: That's true, @matt, the cycle can't be broken if you deliberately sever these two objects from your graph, but is there ever a case where that's not pathological? Would there be a reason to create the two and then try to deallocate them without dismissal?

Comment: It's suspicous, now that I think about this more, @matt, that the property is read-only, but also has a memory management attribute. I think that's a red herring/your doc bug.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Right, the memory management attribute is meaningful only for a `readwrite` property, and even then, only for a _synthesized_ property; it does not tell you what a non-synthesized setter really does even if there is a setter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> 2.UINavigationController stores view controllers in `NSArray`

That is not a given.

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *viewControllers;
```

That in no way indicates that there is an ivar called `_viewControllers` or anything like it. It just tells us that there is some method `-viewControllers` that will return us an `NSArray`, and that there is some method `setViewControllers:` that will accept one, and hints that it will make a copy of it (or at least behave like it made a copy of it). That is *all* it tells us. If you expand an `NSNavigationController` in the debugger, you'll notice that there is no `_viewControllers` ivar listed there.

If you poke around a little, you'll find that `-viewControllers` is not implemented as a synthesized property. It just forwards onto `-childViewControllers` (which is a `UIViewController` property). OK, so doesn't that just move the problem? I mean `-childViewControllers` *is* implemented as `[NSArray arrayWithArray:_childViewControllers]`. Fair enough. You caught me.

But the same logic applies to `[UIViewController navigationController]`. This declaration:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UINavigationController *navigationController
```

does not mean that it actually has a strong link. It just means that if you called `setNavigationController:`, you would expect it to retain it. But you can't call `setNavigationController:`. There is no such method (not even a private one). So all this is really promising is that there is a method called `-navigationController`. And *it's* implemented as a call to `+[UINavigationController _ancestorViewControllerOfClass:allowModalParent:]`. That just passes on to the `UIViewController` implementation, which walks up the `parentViewController` chain looking for a `UINavigationController`. So there's no retain loop; it's dynamically determined.

But your question is still a good one. The header file here is confusing IMO, and I would open a radar against it. `navigationController` should be listed as `assign` or it should say nothing (even if that defaulted to `strong` it would at least not be misleading).

BTW, if this stuff interests you, you really should drop $90 for [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com). It's very good at this kind of exploration.

Comment: Thank you for answer and Hopper link.

Comment: thanks for the Hopper link Rob. If you have an article somewhere about e tools you use - would you share it? In general, it's very, very interesting to learn about a master's tools (no butt kissing here :) ). Cheers!

Comment: 90% of the reverse engineering work I do is Hopper, nm, otool, and strings (and F-script on Mac, though that hasn't been working for me lately). I used to use class-dump a lot, but I've been having trouble finding a good replacement that works on modern apps. But I don't do reverse engineering very seriously; I almost never try to open up an App Store app, for instance (which any serious explorer does regularly).

Answer (score 3):

The `viewControllers` property of `UINavigationController` is defined as

> ```
> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
> ```
>
> The view controllers currently on the navigation stack.

Then there is no problematic retain loop since the navigation controller removes any `UIViewController` from that array when the view controller is dismissed.

A retain loop is an issue when you do not have any mechanism to open the loop by releasing the retained object at some point (using `release` if non-ARC, or setting a strong property to `nil`).

Comment: Where view controller is dismissed in my sample? There is no instructions `B.viewControllers = [NSArray ...]` there is no `[B popViewController]` no `[B popToRootViewController]`. Where it is dismissed?

Comment: The question is not about dismissal. The question is, if A retains B and B retains A, how can both A and B go out of existence _when there are no other references to them_.